# Wordpress: How do I correctly enqueue this javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, callback

I'm having trouble enqueueing a script. I'm not sure why it's not working. I know the script code itself works.

Another question - if I'm trying to include this .js file, should the js code itself be surrounded by `<script></script>`?

**EDIT - ** I forgot to mention that I am making an *extension* to an existing plugin. I want to write the code for enqueuing in my extension's functions.php file. How do I do this? Below is my setup. **Note** this is giving me the error: `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Find_Do_For_Anspress' does not have a method 'fd_enqueue_front' in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 503`

---

My setup

**anspress-question-answer.php**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../find-do-for-anspress/find-do-for-anspress.php'; //I left out most of the other code but this correctly includes the file below
```

**find-do-for-anspress.php**

```
public function includes() {
        require_once( FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'/functions.php' ); // Again, I'm keeping it short and simple
    }
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'fd_enqueue_front'));
function fd_enqueue_front()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'braintree-js', plugin_dir_url( 'braintree-js.js' ) . 'braintree-js.js', array() );
    }
```

**braintree-js.js**

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>

var clientToken = "12345";

braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
  container: "payment-form"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why you have not tried to use `plugins_url()` to get url of `find-do-for-anspress` plugin ?

Comment: plugins_url(  __FILE__  ) bring you the current plugin file, then you can enqueue the js easily.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99067/enqueue-scripts-inside-a-class-in-a-plugin this link will help you get that.

Answer (score 0):

To enqueue scripts is a two step process. First you enqueue your script, then you register the function holding it.

Like so:

```
//Enqueue script in a function
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'braintree-js', plugin_dir_url( 'braintree-js.js' ) . 'braintree-js.js', array() );
}
//Register the function
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

[See Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more details.

On a side note; if you were to enqueue a file from the very same script that you run your file, you would use `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )`. But now that you want to enqueue a file from *another* script, you have to specify the filename to easily get the correct directory.